# D3.js : Removing dynamically added Pie Chart slices

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, d3.js, pie-chart

I am able to generate pie chart and add data to it dynamically, based on user interaction.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L5Q8r/

The problem I am facing is during the data removal from pie-chart.
When the checkbox is unchecked, I am deleting the data from "dataset" and updating the chart.

The chart is getting updated but the previous "slice of pie" is still visible to user.

I tried adding the ".exit().remove()" but no success. Here is what I did:

```
var updateChart = function (dataset) {
        arcs.data(pie(dataset))
            .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("stroke", "white")
                .attr("stroke-width", 0.8)
                .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .attr("d", arc);

            arcs.data(pie(dataset)).exit().remove(); // Executing but not working

        arcs.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);          

        sliceLabel.data(pie(dataset));

        sliceLabel.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")";
            })
            .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
                if (d.value === 0) {
                    return 1e-6;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            });

        sliceLabel.data(pie(dataset))
            .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "arcLabel")
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
                    if (d.value === 0) {
                        return 1e-6;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.data.Population;
                });
        sliceLabel.data(pie(dataset)).exit().remove();//executing but not working       
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here. First, you are binding the data twice:

```
arcs.data(pie(dataset))
// ...
arcs.data(pie(dataset)).exit()...
```

This second time will pick up the arcs you've just added before, which is not what you want. Do the data binding once and save the result in a variable:

```
var sel = arcs.data(pie(dataset));
sel.enter()...
sel.exit()...
```

Which brings me to the second thing. You weren't saving the updated selections anywhere, resulting in problems later on. Calling `.data()` on a selection does modify the underlying data, but does not update the selection. That is, `arcs` refers to the same elements both before and after calling `.data()`, regardless of what you do with `.enter()` etc.

I've fixed both of these issues [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Q8r/2/). For the latter, I'm explicitly reselecting the elements that the data should be bound to (e.g. `arc_grp.selectAll("path")`). There are other ways of doing this, but this one makes explicit what you're working with.

Comment: But now, if I check more than one checkbox, the pie-chart has an "empty slice".

 Also when I uncheck, the data seems to poped up instead from dataset i.e. the data which is added first gets removed in last.

Comment: Hmm, you were missing parts of the tween function. Fixed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Q8r/3/). If you want to impose a specific order on the slices, you'll have to order them and use a key function. At the moment, there's not enough information to do the matching.

Comment: That now works as charm. Will look into the slices ordering using key function. Thanks.