# D3 piecharts: arcs get not removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to implement a pie chart based on the blog entry here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235

I want to enhance the described pie chart by updating the arcs. My code looks like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> <meta charset="utf-8"> <style> body {     font: 10px sans-serif; }

.arc path {     stroke: #fff; } </style> <body>     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>    <script>        var width = 960, height = 500, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range([ "#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00" ]);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {            return d.population;        });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var draw = function(data) {             var g = svg.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(data));

            g.each(function(d, i) {
                var tmp = d3.select(this);
                console.log(tmp);
                tmp.select("path").attr("d", arc).attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return color(d.data.age);
                });

                tmp.select("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                }).attr("dy", ".35em").style("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.age;
                });             });

            g.enter().append("g").attr("class", "arc");

            g.append("path").attr("d", arc).style("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.data.age);           });

            g.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";            }).attr("dy", ".35em").style("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d) {
                return d.data.age;          });

            g.exit().remove();      }

        var startTimer = function startTimer() {            setTimeout(function() {
                var data = [];
                data.push({
                    population : (Math.random() * 100),
                    age : "A"
                });
                data.push({
                    population : (Math.random() * 100),
                    age : "B"
                });
                data.push({
                    population : (Math.random() * 100),
                    age : "C"
                });
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.population = +d.population;
                });
                console.log(data);
                draw(data);
                startTimer();           }, 2000);       };

        startTimer();   </script>
```

Unfortunately it looks like the arcs get not removed as expected. Over time I get more than three arcs (as I would expect it). Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you get your code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) I can have a play around with it.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/yrk9tr4p/1/

Comment: I'll have a look at that later, in the meantime this answer might prove helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173124/d3-js-removing-dynamically-added-pie-chart-slices?rq=1